# Add timeout to hive jdbc connection

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, timeout, hive

How can I add timeout for hive jdbc connection. When ever hive hangs, my application waiting for responses from hive. What I need is, after some specified time(may be in minutes), my application needs to stop listening from hive connection, do the rest of the work.

Answer (score 0):

Use this property in your hive configuration file.

```
<property>
  <name>hive.stats.jdbc.timeout</name>
  <value>30</value>
  <description>Timeout value (number of seconds) used by JDBC connection and statements.</description>
</property>
```

This will be used in login timeout and query timeout. If your query takes more than 30 seconds 
or configured seconds it will return.

Comment: Don’t be fooled, that only for the `stats` package not for the client side jdbc driver.

Comment: The info that it only applies to the stats package has been mentioned in a [hive-user email group post](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hive-user/201302.mbox/%3CFF1DF58D04F11D4291D09795D1A4EF1618657D12FC@SRV-MAIL%3E). It also mentions that (as of 2013-02-06) the natural place to do it - `Statement.setQueryTimeout` - is not implemented yet.